# How to validate that clicking on a link shows a particular section on screen from a very large webpage

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium

I am testing a very large webpage and when I am clicking on a menu item, the related section of the webpage should appear on the screen. Consider the following code:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class WikipediaTest {
private WebDriver driver;
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/soft/chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    driver.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page");
    driver.findElement(By.id("searchInput")).sendKeys("WebDriver");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@type='submit']")).click();
    Thread.sleep(2000 );
    driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Selenium Remote Control")).click();;
    Thread.sleep(5000); 

    // as expected, the section "Selenium Remote Control" section is being displayed on the screen.   
    // I am looking for a way to validate that the section or the text "Selenium Remote Control" is actually visible on the current screen. 

    driver.quit();}
```

}

I am stuck with the part where I can validate that "Selenium Remote Control" is shown on the current screen. My project has many tests like this and I request for support.

We are using Selenium with Java (and Appium on mobile devices) to test this app. Thanks

Comment: The answer is yes, but a one word answer doesn't seem sufficient for an answer. Sounds like you need a getting started tutorial, and then if you run into a specific problem, you could ask here about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like the below example:

Here, I am trying to search for ***"WebDriver"*** in Wikipedia

```
driver.get("https://www.wikipedia.org/");
driver.findElement(By.id("searchInput")).sendKeys("WebDriver");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@type='submit']")).click();
```

Now comes the validation part. The page that contains information about *"WebDriver"* has the title ***"Selenium (Software)"***

```
String title = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#firstHeading")).getText();
if (title.contentEquals("Selenium (software)"))
    System.out.println("Test Passed!");
else
    System.out.println("Test Failed!");
```

So you can define the property of the element using any one of the locators, and then compare.

Comment: Thanks, but actually I need the next step. E.g if I click on 4. References from the top box of the Selenium(Software) page, I need to check that the Reference section is visible on the monitor / screen of my device. Is there any way to do that?